# Which has more functions for Signal and Image Processing - Matlab or Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scientific-computing

Which has more functions for Signal and Image Processing - Matlab or Python?

I am not concerned with efficiency, only with their comprehensiveness in terms of functionality they offer to the programmer. My field is biomedical research. I process lots of sound and image data.

I am familiar with Matlab's Image Processing and Signal Processing toolboxes. But I am completely unfamiliar with Python. I would like to know if Python's numPy, sciPy, plotLib, etc. can match up to Matlab's toolboxes.

Comment: Hmm have a look at what either has to offer and decide? First thing would be: is the following enough for you and are you ready to splash some cash on this toolbox?
http://www.mathworks.nl/products/signal/description1.html

Comment: As for image processing: http://www.mathworks.nl/products/image/description1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab have [Signal processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/) and [Image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/)

Both are really complete. You have the FileExchange where you can found others function that can be usefull. And some people doing wrapper in Mex with big proccessing library like OpenCV.

Python is a greater choice too and I think it will be more efficient. But Matlab still really used and well support.

The python library you talk about are more Linera algebra application, (Decomposition, matrix manipulation, etc...) so you will need to create your own algo after or search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, Jose Unpingco has just released a book on [Signal Processing for Python](https://www.springer.com/engineering/signals/book/978-3-319-01341-1).  The Scientific Python community has a strong tradition within signal processing, particularly for image processing.

You may want to consider this more from the perspective of what tools are available for specific projects you would like to do.  For general advice on choosing a programming environment, you might want to also check out the Academia or Computational Science Stack Exchange websites.